# How can I change permissions in GCP debian VM. I have this error permission denied [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/google_vm_config.lock'

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm running miniconda on GCP debian DeepLearning VM.

I'm basically trying to run this:

```
 embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=embed_model_id,
    model_kwargs={'device': device},
    encode_kwargs={'device': device, 'batch_size': 32}
)
```

and have this error:

> permission denied [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/google_vm_config.lock'

What can I try in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In one of the GitHub discussions I found a working solution. You need to add `GOOGLE_VM_CONFIG_LOCK_FILE` into list of ignore env vars in the function `to_be_ignored` located in this file `lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/cuda_setup/env_vars.py`

[Link](https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues/620) for reference.

Answer (score -2):

type `sudo -s` to get into root user
Then `sudo chown -R user:user /root/google_vm_config.lock`

where user is you.

Comment: Why is that a solution? Changing file ownership for a file created by root and is a lock file is almost always wrong.

Comment: This didnt work